# calculate the euclidean distance in a json file

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

how to calculate the euclidean distance in a json file?

i have a error: no match for 'operator+'

```
{
    "name" : "att5",
    "comment" : "5 capitals of the US (Padberg/Rinaldi)",
    "type" : "TSP",
    "dimension" : 5,
    "capacity" : 10,
    "edge_weight_type" : "ATT",
    "node_coordinates" : [
        [ 6734, 1453 ],
        [ 2233,   10 ],
        [ 5530, 1424 ],
        [  401,  841 ],
        [ 3082, 1644 ]
    ]

}
```

```
s1 = root["node_coordinates"].size();
if (s1 > 0) {
    nodeCoordinates.clear();
nodeCoordinates.resize(s1);
for (int i=0 ; i<s1 ; i++) {
    s2 = root["node_coordinates"][i].size();
    for (int j=0 ; j<s2 ; j++) {
        nodeCoordinates[i].push_back(root["node_coordinates"][i][j].asDouble());
cout << root["node_coordinates"][i][1]+root["node_coordinates"][j][1]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sounds like you need to get a number out of the array item. thats a better question to ask

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. It can be processed only in two ways: it can be stored or it can be transmitted over the network. In order to manipulate the encoded data, the JSON needs to be parsed. The result of the parsing is a data structure equivalent to the one used to generate the JSON. That data structure is not a JSON any more. You cannot calculate anything using the JSON (only its length). You want to calculate the Euclidean distance between some points represented in memory in some data structure. No JSON is involved in the calculation.